# Форматирование вывода в powershell

Tags: powershell

Есть логи в папке, в этих логах я нашел нужные мне данные:
 и все сохранил в переменную:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem  C:\log\1\* -Include *.log 

New-Item -ItemType file -Path C:\log\result.txt –Force



foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $StringMatch = $null
    $StringMatch = select-string $File -pattern  "\[Exception\]|\[304 Not Modified\]"


if ($StringMatch) {out-file -filepath C:\log\result.txt -inputobject $StringMatch }
}
```

Как мне задать нужный формат вывода:
Сам лог:

```
20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War   8 [R:  33] [Ex][Type:Apiion][Err:30][HTTPStatus:NotFound][Message:text: 4950][CorrId:d1ce7555f63803a2]
```

Пример вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тебе нужно замапить на объект и потом уже выводить, как ты хочешь

Comment: @ Senior Automator
а можно подробнее ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[string] $s = "20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8 [R:  33] [Ex][Type:Apiion][Err:30][HTTPStatus:NotFound][Message:text: 4950][CorrId:d1ce7555f63803a2]"
[string] $s2 = "20015-10-01 13:00:53.986 War 8 [R:  33] [Ex][Type:Apiion][Err:33][HTTPStatus:Found][Message:text: 4930][CorrId:d333333333333a2]"

# предположим, что это массив твоих строк из файла 
[array] $loglines =   @($s, $s2)  # для примера возьмум 2

$List = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# идем по массиву 
 $loglines | ForEach-Object {

  $arr = $_.split("\[*\]")

  $Hash = [ordered]@{


  # это название столбца = значение 
  # $_ - это одна строка из лога
  Description =  $arr[0]

  ID =  $arr[1]

  Time =  $arr[0]       

  Status =  $arr[9]

  URL =  "http://"

  Message =  $arr[11]

  CorrId =  $arr[13]

  }

  [void]$List.Add((

  [pscustomobject]$Hash

  ))

  }

$List | Out-GridView -Title 'My Logs'
```

вывод:

```
PS> $List


Description : 20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8 
ID          : R:  33
Time        : 20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8 
Status      : HTTPStatus:NotFound
URL         : http://
Message     : Message:text: 4950
CorrId      : CorrId:d1ce7555f63803a2

Description : 20015-10-01 13:00:53.986 War 8 
ID          : R:  33
Time        : 20015-10-01 13:00:53.986 War 8 
Status      : HTTPStatus:Found
URL         : http://
Message     : Message:text: 4930
CorrId      : CorrId:d333333333333a2


PS > $List[0] | select -Property ID, Time, Status, URL 

ID                                                               Time                                                             Status                                                          URL                                                            
--                                                               ----                                                             ------                                                          ---                                                            
R:  33                                                           20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8                                  HTTPStatus:NotFound                                             http://
```

или так

```
PS > $List[0] | Format-Table 

Description                          ID                                   Time                                 Status                               URL                                  Message                              CorrId                             
-----------                          --                                   ----                                 ------                               ---                                  -------                              ------                             
20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8      R:  33                               20015-10-01 12:00:53.986 War  8      HTTPStatus:NotFound                  http://                              Message:text: 4950                   CorrId:d1ce7555f63803a2
```

красивый вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

остальное зависит от реализации, но принцып такой

Comment: благодарю, а где можно прочитать про все тонкости и нюансы, я просто делал через одно место,а Вы мне глаза открыли)

Comment: @upward опыт, Интернет,  книги, но не помню название уже

Comment: а скажите, я в переменную `$Result` сохраняю результат  `select-string "[R: ]"` а как можно сгруппировать этот результат по этому же параметру?

Comment: @upward не очень понятен ваш вопрос, что хранит в себе $Result?  от какой строки выполняете select-string "[R: ]" ? как понять "сгруппировать этот результат по этому же параметру" ?